# How to set time in datepicker?

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I used to be able to set time in datefield by doing this in 6.2.0.

```
select: function (cmp, v) {
   var d = v;
   d.setHours(23);
   d.setMinutes(59);
   d.setSeconds(59);
   cmp.setValue(d);
}
```

But now in ExtJs7, the setValue() will trigger select event as well. So, it become a loop.

Thus, is there any other way to set time in datefield ?

Comment: try to use setRawValue instead of setValue

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'submitFormat' config property to set default time of the date:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'To',
        name: 'to_date',
        value: new Date(),
        submitFormat: 'Y-m-d 23:59:59' // <-- THIS ONE
    }],
    buttons: [{
        text: "Show Values",
        handler: function() {
            console.log(this.up('form').getValues());
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not change the datefield value after select. I end up use the setRawValue()